# git command to retrieve latest git commit message

Tags: git

I want to retrieve the latest git commit message from my branch , only 'commit' message nothing else ,

I found commands like `git log -1 --pretty=format:%B` which returns below , however i need only commit message "Add columns to list view" , i also tried '%s' and '%b' but no luck.

```
      Merge branch 'mos-changes' into 'uat'

      Add columns to list view

      See merge request mos/mos-changes!103
```

Comment: That *is* the commit message. If you only want part of it then you have to filter out the rest yourself, as for git that entire thing is the message.

Answer (score 4):

```
git show --format=%b -s
```

%b is (message) body (%s is subject if you need that), and -s means don't show the diff.  "Merge branch" may be part of the commit message, in which case you can use grep -v or sed to filter that out.

Comment: Add columns to list view

   See merge request mos/mos-changes!103

Comment: i get above , but i want only commit message "Add columns to list view"

Comment: If you only want part of the commit message, then you need to post-process it as I said in the above.

Answer (score -1):

There are several commands from git to get only commit messages.
git-rev-list is the plumbing command that let's you print the message of a commit.
Use it like this.

```
1. git rev-list --format=%B --max-count=1 <commit> | tail +2
2. git show-branch --no-name <hash>
3. git show -s --format=%s <hash>
4. git log --format=%B -n 1 <commit>
```